# How to hide the full url of a website and only display the domain name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I hide the pages that the user is surfing and just show
him/her the domain name. E.G. www.google.com as opposed to
www.google.com/index.aspx etc...

Thanks

Comment: Thats not a vague question. Its a good question for guys who have lesser or fewer idea regarding url rewriting. @Sheery, u cannot hide entire link instead you can make your url easy to under stand using the url rewriting feature. See my answer below

Comment: One question... why? what possible benefit could come from breaking the way things are meant to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [frameset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) for this, though it is deprecated in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#absent-elements).

Additionally, you break the ability of the user to bookmark pages and make their experience worse.

I recommend against doing such a thing.

Comment: +1 for presenting the desired solution AND afding advise why not to use it